# sda:sda1 keeps showing up in dmesg

Tags: ubuntu, logs, hard-disk, dmesg

dmesg logs is 'filled with' the following :

```
[613051.997981]  sdf: sdf1
[613052.068773]  sdf: sdf1
[613352.060804]  sdc: sdc1
[613653.176468]  sdc: sdc1
```

This just continues on and on about every 300 seconds(only sdc and sdf is shown).

Any reasons why this might be happening?
It makes reading dmesg outputs annoying.

System specs:
1 SSD(sde), 5 HDDs, 500W PSU, Linux 4.10.0-40-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 9 15:37:44

Comment: This line appears when the kernel detects partitions on "new" harddisks. So this line *should* appear exactly once after the harddisk becomes known to the kernel. First thing I'd do is to use `udevadm` to listen to kernel events, and see if some other suspicious events show up.

Comment: This looks like a monitoring software waking up, as 300 seconds = 5 minutes = default delay of monitoring for many things. Do you have things like nagios hitting this server?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek No, I didn't install monitoring software (except webmin, if that counts as it)

Comment: @dirkt udevadm output : https://pastebin.com/QSpnB8Sc
dmesg output(of the same time) : `[718131.072717]  sdf: sdf1`

Comment: `sudo udevadm monitor --udev --property`, don't run a program, and do nothing for 10 mins and wait if you see something. `tee` or redirect to file as required.

Comment: So the system detects `change` events from the harddisks, as if they were devices with changable media - which is strange.

Comment: Directly by SATA cables...?

Comment: Please have a look at `dmesg` directly after boot (or `syslog` entries after boot), look for anything suspicious when it first detects the harddisks. Any kind of SATA-to-XXX bridge in the system?